# How to call the constructor like a function?

Tags: c++, constructor, call

I am trying to create a temporary C++ object for the same of quick invocation in the constructor and nothing else.

For some reason, that's not working

Here's the code:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> string_vec_t;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct visit_items
{
    virtual void action(std::string *s) = 0;
};

void items_visitor(visit_items *v)
{
    string_vec_t l = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
    for (auto &s: l)
        v->action(&s);
}

struct my_visit_items: visit_items
{
public:
    string_vec_t *r;
    my_visit_items(string_vec_t *r /*, int */): r(r)
    {
        items_visitor(this);
    }

    virtual void action(std::string *s) override
    {
        r->push_back(*s);
        printf("visited: %s\n", s->c_str());
    }
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc)
{
    string_vec_t r;
    r.push_back("1");
    my_visit_items(&r /*, 0 */);

    return -1;
}
```

If I have the ctor take an extra argument, then no problem. But as it stand, it does not work and I don't understand the error:

```
1>error C2040: 'r': 'my_visit_items &' differs in levels of indirection from 'string_vec_t'
1>error C2530: 'r': references must be initialized
```

Comment: Why don't you write a function?

Comment: By calling `do_this(&r);` you are passing a `string_vec_t*`, not a `string_vec_t&`

Comment: `do_this(r);` for calling the reference version. Remove the addressof operator.

Comment: I am sorry, the example is wrong.
```
struct do_this: do_what
{
public:
 string_vec_t *r;
 do_this(string_vec_t *r): r(r)
 {
 }

 virtual void action() override
 {
 }
};
```

Comment: @BenS If it's wrong, please edit the question, don't just leave a comment. You should also elaborate on precisely what you mean by 'for some reason, that's not working'.

Comment: Thank you @john, I fixed the problem. I feel bad for not getting the code right the first time then getting downvoted for something silly.

Comment: The line  "my_visit_items(&r /*, 0 */);"  generates "error: conflicting declaration ‘my_visit_items& r’"  Its not what you want to do, but this error can be cleared with "my_visit_items  mvi(&r);"

Comment: Your description "create a temporary C++ object for the same of quick invocation in the constructor" and several of your coding choices suggest to me that you might be interested in a functor ... but in the functors with which I am familiar, the ctor and dtor both do-nothing (which makes them very quick) and "operator()" does all the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_visit_items(&r /*, 0 */);` is a declaration of the `my_visit_items` reference `r`, just like `my_visit_items &r;` would have been. Try uniform Initialization instead. You should also try to avoid passing pointers to strings and vectors around. The code you showed would work fine without pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef std::vector<std::string> string_vec_t;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct visit_items {
    virtual void action(const std::string& s) = 0;
    virtual ~visit_items() = default;
};

void items_visitor(visit_items& v) {
    string_vec_t l = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
    for(auto& s : l) v.action(s);
}

struct my_visit_items : visit_items {
    string_vec_t& r;
    my_visit_items(string_vec_t& r) :
        visit_items{},
        r(r)
    {
        items_visitor(*this);
    }

    virtual void action(const std::string& s) override {
        r.push_back(s);
        std::cout << "Visited: " << s << "\n";
    }
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    string_vec_t r;
    r.push_back("1");
    my_visit_items{r};    //   { } instead of ( )

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ted. That was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to pass a reference then you need to call `do_this(r);` 
With calling `do_this(&r)` you are passing a pointer to `r`.

Further you can call the constructor (theoretically) directly with
`do_this::do_this(r);`

But why not using a function when you want to  have a function? Not every compiler allows this without setting some compiler options explicitly (e.g., gcc requires -fpersmissive).
If the reason is that you want to implement your function only once, then call the function from the constructor.
If you want to have a function that is encapsulated in class without requiring attributes of the class, you can also use a `static` class member function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had a wrong code snippet and I have updated it accordingly. Please delete your answer and my comments to better reflect this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to errors.

On my Linux, g++-v7:

If you turn on enough compiler flags, you might discover that the compiler is warning about this struct:

```
struct visit_items
{
    virtual void action(std::string *s) = 0;
};
```

with

```
// warning: ‘struct visit_items’ has virtual functions and 
// accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
```

Note: This warning triggers 2 other issues (where the class is used).

This all clears up when you provide a virtual default dtor

```
struct visit_items  
{
   virtual ~visit_items() = default;
   virtual void action(std::string *s) = 0;
};
```